# Instantiate Java anonymous inner class with generic using Class in variable

Tags: java, generics, instantiation, anonymous-inner-class

Is it possible in Java 7 to instantiate an anonymous inner class with a generic type using a `Class` object that I have in hand?

Here's the simplified version of the generic class I'm trying to instantiate:

```
abstract class DomainBuilder<E> {

    private final Class<E> entityClass

    public DomainBuilder() {
        this.entityClass = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    ...
}
```

Creating an anonymous inner class when I specify the class I want to build at compile time works fine:

```
DomainBuilder builder = new DomainBuilder<MyDomainClass>() {}
```

I'd like to be able to make it so that I can use a `Class` variable that I've determined at run-time like this, but haven't figured out how to yet:

```
Class clazz = MyDomainClass.class
...
DomainBuilder builder = new DomainBuilder<clazz>() {}
```

I've also tried creating methods along these lines without luck:

```
Class clazz = MyDomainClass.class
DomainBuilder builder = builderFor(clazz)

public static DomainBuilder<T> builderFor(Class<T> t) {
    return new DomainBuilder<T>(entityManager){}
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create an entirely separate constructor for when the `Class` object is being passed in directly.  You can't infer it again the way you're trying to.

Comment: So you mean one where my `DomainBuilder` takes a `Class` argument and just sets that variable directly? That might work for my use case, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to make it so that I can use a Class variable that
>   I've determined at run-time like this, but haven't figured out how to
>   yet:
>
> ```
>  Class clazz = MyDomainClass.class ... DomainBuilder 
>  builder = new  DomainBuilder<clazz>() {}
> ```

we can't actually do it this way. Because by doing so, we are not defining a `class Type` in the diagonal `<>`, rather passing an object `claszz` of type `Class`.